# finding all the queries executed on a particular day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to retrieve all the queries executed on a database on a particular day eg(12/12/2015). How can i do it?

Comment: Run SQL Server Profiler.

Comment: Do you have log backups?

Comment: @DuncanHowe - i don't know how do i find out?

Comment: You meant committed transactions?

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: @OrsonDCunha - first off, check the recovery model of your database. In SSMS, right click on the database in question, click properties, and at the top of the dialog it should tell what your recovery model is. If it isn't Full Recovery, you will find it very difficult.

Comment: If you mean other than updates / inserts, it's not possible, unless you're explicitly capturing them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following SQL query:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
       ST.text AS sqlText,
       QS.execution_count AS EXECCount,
       QS.total_elapsed_time AS spendTime,
       QS.total_logical_reads AS logicRead,
       QS.total_logical_writes AS logicWrite,
       QS.total_physical_reads AS logicReadCount,       
       QS.creation_time AS executeTime ,  
       QS.*
FROM   sys.dm_exec_query_stats QS
       CROSS APPLY 
sys.dm_exec_sql_text(QS.sql_handle) ST
WHERE  QS.creation_time BETWEEN '2015-08-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-09-02 11:00:00' 
ORDER BY
     QS.total_elapsed_time DESC
```

Comment: This fetches queries where the plan was **created** on that day, and are still in plan cache and since the OP is talking over a month in the past, this is most likely useless for that case.